# passing variable as upload directory

Tags: php, mysql, fine-uploader, phreeze

I'm new to using fineuploader, with php/javascript, and run into something I cannot find a solution for.

I have a php5 mvc file, created using Phreeze, in which data from a MySQL database is read and shown, like this:

```
    <% items.each(function(item) { %>
        <tr id="<%= _.escape(item.get('codigo')) %>">
            <td><%= _.escape(item.get('nombreHo') || '') %></td>
            <td><%= _.escape(item.get('desHo') || '') %></td>
            <td><%= _.escape(item.get('dirFoto') || '') %></td>
            <td><%= _.escape(item.get('extrasHo') || '') %></td>
        </tr>
    <% });
```

When I click on this table I want the dirFoto variable to be used as the directory to upload the photo's to for this item.

I have two questions:
What is the best way to have this information available in the endpoint/handler files? I tried params, but am not sure this is correct.

```
request: {
           endpoint: 'libs/FineUploader/server/endpoint.php',
           params: {
           updir: this.dirFoto
           }
         },
```

The second question is how to use this variable, and specifically also how to prevent the "getUniqueTargetPath", since I want to determine the directory, without fineuploader altering this.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: I think that after the page is rendered all you would have is something like `<td>/somepath/somepicture.jpg</td>`. not a variable you could refer to...
besides the variable would have the last know value because it has been set over and over in the foreach... You could give each <td>  an unique id with the value of `<%= _.escape(item.get('dirFoto') || '') %>` then your js could get the right directory with get_element_by_id()...

Comment: `<td id="dirphoto_<%= _.escape(item.get('codigo')) %>" value="<%= _.escape(item.get('dirFoto') || '') %>"><%= _.escape(item.get('dirFoto') || '') %></td>` for instance

Comment: I would think the correct value is already available in the tablerow ID 
<tr id="<%= _.escape(item.get('codigo')) %>">?
I would just need to find how to insert that in the parameter to pass this along.

Comment: I did some more checking and it seems I need to use the .closest function to get the tr ID value. 
However, how to incorporate that in Fineuploader is still a mystery to me, I'll keep trying, but if someone knows the answer that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Okay, I'm at a loss about how to use the <tr> ID value as a parameter for Fine Uploader, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to have this information available in the endpoint/handler files?

Pass them as parameters, as you have illustrated in your code.

> how to use this variable

Access it in the POST request sent by Fine Uploader. If you are using PHP, you can access this using `$_REQUEST` or `$_POST`.